# I want to get back to the options after inputting something to the file with choice 1

Tags: c

I need to be able to go to choice 1, add a record to the file, and then return to the menu to do another option. I also need to be able to do this for choice 2.

> Code snippet

```
while(program == 1){
            while(menu == 1){
                    num = 0;
                    printf("(1)Add record, (2)View records, or (3)Quit.\n");
                    scanf("%d", &choice);


                    if(choice == 1){
                            menu =0;
                            inv = fopen("recs", "w");
                                            printf("<Item Number> <Item Category> <cost> <city> <date>\n");
                                            fscanf(inv, "%d %c %c %c %c %c %c %c %c %c %c %.2f %c %c %c %c %c %c$
                                            &cost, &city[0], &city[1], &city[2], &city[3], &city[4], &city[5], &$
                            fclose(inv);
                            if(num >= 1){
                                    menu =1;
                                    continue;
                            }
                    }

                    else if(choice == 2){
                            menu =0;
                            int c;
                            inv = fopen("recs", "r");
                            if(inv){
                                    while((c = getc(inv)) != EOF)
                                            putchar(c);
                                    fclose(inv);
                            }
                    }

                    else if(choice == 3){
                            printf("Iventory program terminated\n");
                            menu = 0;
                            program =0;
                            break;
                    }

                    else;
            }
    }
     return(0);
}
```

Comment: What exactly is your question/problem?  We can help with specific questions, but we can't write entire solutions...

Comment: IMHO you should break your code into smaller functions first to make it more readable it'll help coder, reviewer ,maintainer and everyone trying to answer this question

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `menu = 0;` in case one and two it works fine.